# Microsoft Lync 2010 - Limiting who can contact who

Tags: lync, lync-2010

Is there a way to limit who is able to contact who within Lync 2010? Perhaps something based on the AD group?

I.E. Members of the Customer Service department can only Lync their supervisors, Accounting Department can only Lync the Accounting department, etc.

Answer (score 2):

No. The only option would be to build several groups of users that use different Lync servers (pools) this doesn't change even if you decide to upgrade to Skype for Business. You can't build contact groups by default as well. You might be able to only let users see certain "groups" of users by [partitioning](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/11/2014/10/06/lync-server-2013-guidance-series-can-i-partition-global-address-list/) the global address list but as long as the users are on the same pool and know the address of each other they would be able to communicate.